# How to add key-value pairs in state object while iterating through a for loop in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a Json Object (say obj1,obj2,obj3) in state and add the key-value pairs in another object in state(deepLanguageCollection) to make sure that all the keys have a cumulative value which is the sum of all the values for a given key in obj1,2,3 respectively.

The reason I am transferring the contents of obj1,2,3 to deepLanguageCollection is because obj1,2,3 have some common keys. I want to have unique values in deepLanguageCollection with the values as their cumulative sum in Obj1,2,3.

When I try to do this, the deepLanguageCollection object only registers the last entry. Although if I add the key-value pairs directly in state, then it works perfectly!

Why does this happen even after using the spread operator? And how do I fix this?

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.Obj1).length; i++) {    

 key = Object.keys(this.state.Obj1)[i];
 value = this.state.Obj1[Object.keys(this.state.Obj1)[i]];

this.setState({
 deepLanguageCollection: {
   ...this.state.deepLanguageCollection,
   [key] :this.state.deepLanguageCollection[key]?this.state.deepLanguageCollection[key]+value:value,//->This always pushes the LAST key-value pair in deepLanguageCollection object without the sum, just the last entry in Obj 3
   },

 [key]: value,//->this pushes all key-value pairs meaning unique keys and value sum in state perfectly
 })
}
```